# How to return multiple images and their corresponding id from Django to reactJS

Tags: reactjs, django, django-media

I want to send multiple images and their corresponding id from `Django` to `react.js`.

I tried to return dictionary of images with id as key in this format:

```
{id1:image1, id2:image2}
```

here,

> id = <class 'int'>

> image = <class 'django.core.files.base.File'>

but I only received this in `react.js`

```
{id1, id2}
```

and there are no media images in the received dictionary.

How can return multiple images and their corresponding `id` in `Django`?

Comment: Could you please add an info what do you get on the network level in your browser when your API is called? You can check that in your browser's developer tools -> Network tab

Comment: You can return for example URLs to images or BASE64 encoded image binaries. What do you return? ImageField objects? Please edit your question and add more specifics. Show how you construct response, what are "images", where you take them from.

Comment: @IvanStarostin image type is <class 'django.core.files.base.File'> and id type is int.

Comment: Please edit your question, add models, views, serializers or whatever is involved in _returning images_.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71798918/cannot-find-images-in-react-response